# Beginner question - why should I use nested loop in this example?

Tags: swift

I’m trying to learn Swift. I’m now on lesson 5 of “Swift Tutorial for Beginners” by Code with Chris. I’m finishing all the challenges he prepared, but I’m stuck at Challenge 5, which is to print a pattern like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I don’t get why should I use nested loop.

According to the completed challenge file, the code should look like this:

```
var drawPixel:String = "*"
var height:Int = 5
var tempRow:String = ""

for columnPixel in 1...height {
    tempRow = ""
    for _ in 1...columnPixel{
        tempRow += drawPixel
    }
    print(tempRow)
}
```

but

```
var drawPixel:String = "*"
var height:Int = 5
var tempRow:String = ""

for _ in 1...height{
    tempRow += drawPixel
    print(tempRow)
}
```

also works the way it should and seems way simplier. I understand my method (second code), but not the one I’m supposed to use. **My questions:**

1. Why is there a nested loop?
2. why in first example nested loop refers to columnPixel (for _ in 1...columnPixel) since it is already defined that it should repeat the loop to 5?
3. Lastly, why "print(tempRow)" is outside of a nested loop?

Here's the challenge: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DI-4RkYkRl8EPY17TOwfK8gCl--KMdqLEPP-hz6QHI0/edit# (scrool down to Challenge 5)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To make your question clearer, you should include the desired output of the code (i.e. what you are supposed to do in Challenge 5).

Comment: The first example creates a new string from scratch to print for each iteration of the outer loop, the second re-uses the string and modifies it. Sure the second one is shorter but since I have no idea what the purpose of the exercise is I don't know if that means it's better

Comment: I just edited the post and added the link to the Challenge 5 - please take a look. :)

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, so I've added the requirements of the challenge in. Hopefully you don't mind.

Comment: Not a problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there a nested loop?

The outer loop and inner loop serve different purposes. Each iteration of the outer loop prints one row. Each iteration of the inner loop "constructs" the string that is printed.

> why in first example nested loop refers to columnPixel (for _ in 1...columnPixel) since it is already defined that it should repeat the loop to 5?

`columnPixel` is referred in the inner loop because the number of iterations of the inner loop changes depending on which iteration of the outer loop:

- In the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop loops only once. The string constructed is `*`
- In the second iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop loops twice. The string constructed is `**`
- In the third iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop loops three times. The string constructed is `***`
- and so on...

Notice that `columnPixel` changes with each iteration of the outer loop. In the first iteration it's 1, in the second iteration it's 2, etc. This is why we say "loop `columnPixel` lots of times" in the inner loop.

> Lastly, why "print(tempRow)" is outside of a nested loop?

We only want to print the *constructed* string, not while we are constructing it.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand now, but I need to make sure about one element:

1. tempRow = "" is in the outer loop to let the compiler know how many times should it repeat the nested loops? If I remove tempRow = "" from the outer loop, the console prints four * more each time (based on the number of nested loops I suppose?). I added three more nested loops just to check If I think right.

Comment: `tempRow` is the variable that stores your partially-constructed row. Each time you begin constructing a new row (i.e. just before the inner loop), **you need to get rid of the row that's constructed by the previous iteration of the loop.** That's what `tempRow = ""` does. @kacper3355

Comment: @kacper3355 The number of times the inner loop needs to run is determined by `columnPixel`. If it is 1, the inner loop is run once. If it is 2, the inner loop is run twice.